# Sum of salaries in family structure in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, sum, structure, addition

I want to get a sum of salaries of children of family. I work in Turbo Prolog. As I understand, howManyChildrenSalary works well in Visual Prolog.

```
family (fm("Ivan","Ivanov", dat(1,"may",1980),wor("ingener",0)),
fm("Anna","Ivanov", dat(15, "january",1945),wor("doctor",1800)),
[fm("Oleg","Ivanov", dat(22, "march", 1970), wor("student",720)),
fm("Antin","Ivanov", dat(22, "march", 1970), wor("student",820)),
fm("Inna", "Ivanov", dat(7, "july", 1975), wor("pupil",100))]).    

howManyChildrenSalary([],0).
howManyChildrenSalary([fm(_,_,_,wor(_,Salary))|Children],N):-howManyChildren(Children,N1),N=Salary+N1.    

profit (Surname,Average) :-
family(X,Y,Children),
X = fm(_,Surname,dat(_,_,Year),wor(_,0)),
Y = fm(_,Surname,_,wor(_,SalaryMom)),
Year > 2014-40,
howManyChildrenSalary(Children,ChildrenSalary),
howManyChildren(Children,N),
Average = (SalaryMom+ChildrenSalary)/(N+2).
```

So in my case I get ChildrenSalary=720+1+1=722 instead if ChildrenSalary=720+820+100=1640.
Why do I get this and how to fix it?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a typo:

```
howManyChildrenSalary([fm(_,_,_,wor(_,Salary))|Children],N):-
   howManyChildrenSalary(Children,N1),N=Salary+N1.
```

assuming

```
howManyChildren(Children,N) :- length(Children,N).
```